# Do While Loop to Send Multiple Emails by Row

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am looking for help with some VBA code.

I have an excel sheet with multiple columns and rows. Each row represents a different report which I must create and send via email to specific recipients. Each report is business day specific. What I am looking to do is the following. Automatically create an email for each row in a given business day. The code I pasted below works perfectly to create one email, but I would like to avoid having a macro button for each row.

I'd like the code to loop for each row in a given business day. For example, if business day 1 has 10 reports, clicking the macro would generate 10 different unique emails.

I've tried to create a do while loop, but I am running into some problems with that method and I am not entirely sure how to address the subject and body which are concatenated text cells, unique to each row.

```
Sub makeReports(dueDate As Date)

Dim reportsRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strBody As String

'Determine reports range (from uppermost cell to last nonempty cell in column)
Set reportsRange = Range("B5", Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each xlCell In reportsRange
    If xlCell.Value = dueDate Then
        strTo = xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
        strCc = xlCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        strSubject = xlCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
        strBody = xlCell.Offset(0, 11).Value

        Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strCc, strSubject, strBody)
    End If

Next xlCell

Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub


 Sub createMail(objOutlook As Outlook.Application, strTo As String, strCc As String, strSubject   As String, strBody As String)

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)


With objMail
    .To = strTo
    .cc = strCc
    .Subject = strSubject
    .Body = strBody
    .display
    ' If you want to send:
    '.Send
End With

Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub


Sub test()
  Call makeReports(1)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Call makeReports(Date)
End Sub
```

**Third Edit:**

I have attached a screenshot of the workday function to determine the correct deliverable day

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you considered finding the last row and using a `For` loop to loop through your rows?

Comment: Great use of automation.  If you could revise your question with a few additional details to the ones you've already provided:  Step By step logical breakdown of your decision making process for EACH row.  As in, where is the workday column?  Is it a number or Text workday?  What decides which columns are used in building the subject, and body?  That sort of thing.  Make it very simple, and break it down into separate statement like this:  1. I look at a row, if the value in column B = "monday" then 2. I look at Column C.  If that is THIS then 3.  I merge columns F & G for the body, and...

Comment: You also need to tell us how to identify the number of rows to process. I assume you would first pick a day (which is a column?), then find the bottom of that column and only process cells that contain a value for each row. Are the days like 1-31 or Mon-Fri?

Comment: Hello all. I can help clarify a bit. The workday can be anything that denotes a business day. I was thinking we could just use 1 for business day one, 2 for business day two and so forth. The number of rows can change in the future as we add and delete reports, so It would be helpful if the code would do sometype of countif on the business day column to see how many business day 1 reports we have. Let me know if I can clarify any further. I did post my updated code above for your reference. I built in a for loop and I think I am getting close.

Comment: I am now getting a Run-time error 91 because an Object Variable or With block variable is not set. This appears after the first email is generated, I suppose when the code loops to the next i. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your reports for a given business day are stored in column A, the following code should get you started:

```
Sub SendReports(columnLetter As String)

    Dim reportsRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range

    'Determine reports range (from uppermost cell to last nonempty cell in column)
    Set reportsRange = Range(columnLetter & "1", Range(columnLetter & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each xlCell In reportsRange
        Call CreateMail(xlCell.value)
    Next xlCell

End Sub
```

To test it:

```
Sub test()
 Call SendReports("A")
End Sub
```

Just change CreateMail so it accepts rngBody as a parameter.

**Edit:**

The following code works on my PC. Make sure you set a reference to the Outlook Object Library (in the VBA editor, select Tools>References and tick Microsoft Outlook ##.# Object Library (where ##.# is your installed version)) and delete all empty report lines in column A.

```
  Sub makeReports(businessDay As Integer)

    Dim reportsRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim strTo As String
    Dim strCc As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strBody As String

    'Determine reports range (from uppermost cell to last nonempty cell in column)
    Set reportsRange = Range("A5", Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each xlCell In reportsRange
        If xlCell.Value = businessDay Then
            strTo = xlCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
            strCc = xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
            strSubject = xlCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
            strBody = xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value

            Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strCc, strSubject, strBody)
        End If

    Next xlCell

    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub


Sub createMail(objOutlook As Outlook.Application, strTo As String, strCc As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String)

    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)


    With objMail
        .To = strTo
        .cc = strCc
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Body = strBody
        .display
        ' If you want to send:
        '.Send
    End With

    Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub


Sub test()
 Call makeReports(1)
End Sub
```

Now all you need is some logic to figure out the current business day.

**Edit2:**

This is a modified version of the code accepting a due date as parameter and taking into account the additional column you have inserted:

```
  Sub makeReports(dueDate As Date)

    Dim reportsRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim strTo As String
    Dim strCc As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strBody As String

    'Determine reports range (from uppermost cell to last nonempty cell in column)
    Set reportsRange = Range("B5", Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each xlCell In reportsRange
        If xlCell.Value = dueDate Then
            strTo = xlCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
            strCc = xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
            strSubject = xlCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
            strBody = xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value

            Call createMail(objOutlook, strTo, strCc, strSubject, strBody)
        End If

    Next xlCell

    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Add a command button onto your worksheet and enter the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Call makeReports(Date)
End Sub
```

This should open one mail for every report due today.

Comment: Thank you for the response, silentsurfer. I greatly appreciate the advice. I'm not sure I understand how to incorporate this new subroutine into my current code. Obviously, I am a VBA newbie. I'll work with it a bit and come back with any questions.

Comment: @TWDeac, I'm happy to help. What part of the code is causing you trouble? SendReports loops through all rows in the column specified by columnLetter, starting from the first(A1) to the last row containing data, and calls CreateMail, passing the current cell value as as the rngBody parameter. If this is not what you need, it might be helpful to post a screenshot of how your data is laid out on your worksheet.

Comment: Silentsurfer, here is a screenshot of my data. There would be much more data, but this gives you an idea. [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/28v5dtg.png)

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. I greatly appreciate your assistance! I'll work on the logic for the current business day and get back to you with my solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @TWDeac, glad you like it. Hint: you may want to take a look at the Weekday() function.

Comment: I'm just now getting around to working on this. The holidays have been a mess. I have my business day situation straightened out using the WORKDAY() function. Ideally, I would have the macro set so that when I click the button, it would look at a cell which is showing today's date(updated every time I open the worksheet). Then it would look through my range of due dates, and open an email for each matching date. For example: If there were 3 reports due today, January 2, 2015, it would open 3 email messages. If tomorrow had 5 reports, it would open 5 messages, etc..

Comment: as per usual, I know what I want to do, but I'm having difficulty getting the code correct.

Comment: @TWDeac Please update your question showing how you are using the WORKDAY() function to determine your business day.

Comment: I have posted a screenshot. It seems fairly straightforward and would be very powerful if I could get it working. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for the extra code. I can't seem to get it to work with the command button. I've edited the above question with the updates. Let me know what you think. It doesn't give any errors, but it also doesn't output anything.

Comment: I have only used your code since you began helping. I posted the full macro code above if you want to take a look.

Comment: Could it be something with how I implemented the command button?

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the first comment. I added a new command button and entered the code, but it now gives me a compile error: Sub or function not defined. I'm sure this is some rookie error that I am missing. I really appreciate your help on this. I know it must be frustrating! The site prompted me to move this to chat, but I do not have enough reputation to do so. Not sure if you can do it from your end..

Comment: I'm afraid you need at least 20 rep to chat. I guess it is best to just delete unnecessary comments in this case. Please tell me which call is throwing the error (i.e. which line of code). Make sure that you have added a reference to the Microsoft Outlook Object library, and that you have pasted the code for procedures makeReports(dueDate As Date) and createMail into your vba editor (double click on the correct worksheet node in your project explorer)